# How to break up MYSQL results with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Happy Sunday to all

Just a quick question: I am struggling to query my server in an intelligent way. I want to query the server for the latest news articles in the db and fetch the title, content, date, etc.

I also want to output the results in a JQuery tabs widget so that users can see three at a time... SO, this basically means that between every three results I need to output a  to make sure that the stuff will be picked up by the JQuery as appropriate.

At the moment I don't know how to do that. I don't know how to break up the results into separate group and insert code where I need to. I tried building an array.. I tried to reset the pointer/cursor, etc. alas to no avail. So I am basically running the query multiple times (see the below) which is obviously a very crappy way of achieving the desired results. Any ideas how to do this more elegantly / efficiently?

Thanks for all your help

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('*****','*****','*****','ajax_demo');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM user2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
$sql2= "SELECT * FROM user2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3,3";
$sql3= "SELECT * FROM user2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6,3";
$sql4= "SELECT * FROM user2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9,3";
$sql5= "SELECT * FROM user2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12,3";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
$result3 = mysqli_query($con,$sql3);
$result4 = mysqli_query($con,$sql4);
$result5 = mysqli_query($con,$sql5);

echo "<div class=\"\" id=\"content1\">\n"; 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

      {

      echo '<div class="snippet2"><a href="#item'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Title'] . "</a><br/>";
      echo $row['Date'] . " &nbsp | &nbsp ";
      echo $row['Commodity']. "  &nbsp| &nbsp;  ";
      echo "<img id=".$row['id']." onClick=\"reply_click(this.id)\" src=\"images/emico.png\" width=\"17\" height=\"12\" /><br />\n";
      echo "<br/></div>";
      }
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo "</div>\n";
echo "<div class=\"\" id=\"content2\">\n";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

      {

      echo '<div class="snippet2"><a href="#item'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Title'] . "</a><br/>";
      echo $row['Date'] . " &nbsp | &nbsp ";
      echo $row['Commodity']. "  &nbsp| &nbsp;  ";
      echo "<img id=".$row['id']." onClick=\"reply_click(this.id)\" src=\"images/emico.png\" width=\"17\" height=\"12\" /><br />\n";
      echo "<br/></div>";
      }
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo "</div>\n";
echo "<div class=\"\" id=\"content3\">\n";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {

      {

      echo '<div class="snippet2"><a href="#item'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Title'] . "</a><br/>";
      echo $row['Date'] . " &nbsp | &nbsp ";
      echo $row['Commodity']. "  &nbsp| &nbsp;  ";
      echo "<img id=".$row['id']." onClick=\"reply_click(this.id)\" src=\"images/emico.png\" width=\"17\" height=\"12\" /><br />\n";
      echo "<br/></div>";
      }
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo "</div>\n";
echo "<div class=\"\" id=\"content4\">\n";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) {

      {

      echo '<div class="snippet2"><a href="#item'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Title'] . "</a><br/>";
      echo $row['Date'] . " &nbsp | &nbsp ";
      echo $row['Commodity']. "  &nbsp| &nbsp;  ";
      echo "<img id=".$row['id']." onClick=\"reply_click(this.id)\" src=\"images/emico.png\" width=\"17\" height=\"12\" /><br />\n";
      echo "<br/></div>";
      }
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo "</div>\n";
echo "<div class=\"\" id=\"content5\">\n";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) {

      {

      echo '<div class="snippet2"><a href="#item'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Title'] . "</a><br/>";
      echo $row['Date'] . " &nbsp | &nbsp ";
      echo $row['Commodity']. "  &nbsp| &nbsp;  ";
      echo "<img id=".$row['id']." onClick=\"reply_click(this.id)\" src=\"images/emico.png\" width=\"17\" height=\"12\" /><br />\n";
      echo "<br/></div>";
      }
}
echo "</div>\n";


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Use a `counter` inside a `while`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is one query using a counter in your loop to track with

```
$ctr=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) {

     if($ctr % 3===0){
      /*  do something every third pass*/
     }
      /* increment counter*/
      $ctr++
}
```

Comment: oooh just like in VBA :-) Let me try it out